# Help converting vBulletin 3.6.4 to phpBB 3

Tags: php, mysql, vbulletin, phpbb3

So I've been researching, and it looks like converters only exist from vBulletin 3.x to phpBB 2.0 and then from phpBB 2.0 to 3.0

I would rather not do a two-step conversion, but I don't want to do a custom by-hand conversion, either.

So, any suggestions? I've looked all over on Stack, Google, and any forums I could find, but with no luck. Anything that even touches vBulletin 3.x seems to date back to 2007.

I know it's old-as-my-grandma software, but I can't help it. I have only been working at this job for a year or so and the Web Devs before me had an "if it ain't broke don't fix it" attitude so now I"m in this pickle.

Reason for converting to phpBB: vBulletin costs $250/year and we don't need a whole community, we built one in house. Just a forum that works and looks nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I found the answer to this question, in case anyone else needs to know. I started by downloading phpBB 2.0, and converted everything to there, then converted everything from phpBB 2.0 to 3.0. It was a pain, and I had to make some custom login functions so that all my users' passwords weren't lost (as the password reset function is really weak).

Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Actually a Vbulletin 3 to PHPBB 3 Converter has been available for some time now. Take a look at this thread on the official PHPBB support forum in the Converters Subforum:

http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=1722325

Pete